# In an alert I'm getting [object object] instead of the values

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an `alert()` I'm getting `[object object]`. I'm wondering for not getting the values in the `<div>`.

```
var popUser = $("<div/>").attr("id", "jchat_user_" + ae + "_popup").addClass("jchat_tabpopup jchat_tabopen").attr("dir", "ltr").html(toolbarLanguageHTML + '<div class="jchat_tabcontent messagelist"><div class="jchat_tabcontenttext private"></div><div class="jchat_tabcontentinput">' + writeElement + "</div>" + webrtcTrigger + '<div class="jchat_trigger_emoticon"></div><div class="jchat_trigger_fileupload"></div><div class="jchat_trigger_export"></div><div class="jchat_trigger_delete"></div><div class="jchat_trigger_refresh"></div>' + infoTrigger + historyTrigger + geolocationTrigger + sendTrigger + "</div>").appendTo($("body"));

alert(popUser);
```

Comment: Because you are alerting an object.

Comment: can you tell me a correct way of alerting  a div.

Comment: try `alert($("div#jchat_user_" + ae + "_popup").text())`

Comment: Why did you use the php tag?

Comment: _"can you tell me a correct way of alerting a div"_ a div is actually a DOM Object, what _part_ of the div would you like to alert? The text, the outer HTML tag, the ID, what?

Comment: You can use `console.log(popUser)` to verify value of that variable, value will display in console.

Comment: It's because `alert()` coerces all types to a string, and `popUser` is an object. It's for this *exact* reason that you should not use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log()` or `console.dir()` instead

Comment: whole part including Id

Comment: yes I have tried with console.log() its not working

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning an object (DOM element) to your

```
var popUser
```

thats why alert showing [object object].

If you want to show your HTML markup in alert than You can't do this in standard alert box. You'll have to create your own, for example, jQuery UI Dialog: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

or you can use console.log() to check popUser object for your development purposes.

Comment: This seems to be more a comment that has already been said, rather than an answer

Comment: Ok what should i do now to get a whole div element in alert? sontosh\

Comment: @Pradeeprajendiren i have edited my answer for more detail.

Comment: @santosh for the testing purpose I have given as alert... if get the value in alert I will append in HTML page. but my problem in alert itself I'm getting an answer.

Comment: @Pradeeprajendiren then use console.log() instead. alert won't help to show objects like in your case.